# Java happens-before relationship

Tags: java, synchronization

Although there are a lot of posts on SO and elsewhere about the happens-before relationship, I am having a surprisingly hard time finding a definitive answer to my question.

Consider the two Java threads:

initially, `flag == false` and `data == 0`

T1

```
data = 42;
synchronized(m) {
  flag = true;
}
```

T2

```
boolean f;
synchronized(m) {
  f = flag;
}
if (f) {
  int x = data;
}
```

According to the code above, I believe `f` could either be assigned the value `true` or `false`, there is no guaruntee. Is this correct?

Now, if the two `synchronized` statements were changed to `synchronized(flag)`, I think the instruction `flag = true` will always happen before the instruction `f = flag`, and thus `f` will always be assigned the value `true`. Is this correct?

Comment: if the `T2` run first , it will get you `false` ,so which thread you run it first ???

Comment: You should never synchronize on a mutable field, and you can't synchronize on a primitive, it has to be an Object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, synchronized make no guarantees about which `Thread` gets there first. In only guarantees that more that one `Thread` cannot access the synchronized block at a time.

Think of a `synchronized` block as a room with a lock on the door. We have no idea who will get to the door first, but once they do they go in and lock the door.

Other people must wait until the person in the room is ready to leave and unlocks the door. Once that happens everyone races to get in the door again.

It all depends on the order in which you set your `Thread`s off. But even then there are no guarantees as the JVM may suspend `Thread`s and `Thread`s `yield` to one-another randomly. In the analogy - the guy in the lead to get to the door might trip on a banana peel. No likely, but always possible.

If you want to have guarantees then you need to `wait`/`notify` - so that the reading thread checks the `flag`, and if it's `false`, suspends itself in a loop.

The writing thread then sets the `flag` and notifies the lock monitor which wakes the reading thread.

Here is an example using the `Lock` and `Condition` api from Java 5. I'm not saying that you *have* to use that in preference to `synchronized` and `wait`/`notify` - it's just an example I had lying around that I adapted.

The `Reader` acquires the `lock` and then checks the `ready` flag in a loop. If the flag is `false` it `await`s on the condition. This atomically releases the `lock` and suspends the `Thread`.

The `Writer` meanwhile acquires the `lock` and sets the `data` and the `ready` flag. It then calls `signalAll` and releases the `lock`.

This wakes the `Reader` which then reads the `ready` as `true` and proceeds to the `print` statement.

The output will always be `42` (never `-1`).

```
public class App {

    static volatile boolean ready = false;
    static volatile int data = -1;

    private static class Reader implements Runnable {

        private final Lock lock;
        private final Condition condition;

        public Reader(Lock lock, Condition condition) {
            this.lock = lock;
            this.condition = condition;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while (!ready) {
                    try {
                        condition.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        //oh well
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(data);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Writer implements Runnable {

        private final Lock lock;
        private final Condition condition;

        public Writer(Lock lock, Condition condition) {
            this.lock = lock;
            this.condition = condition;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                data = 42;
                ready = true;
                condition.signalAll();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        executorService.execute(new Reader(lock, condition));
        executorService.execute(new Writer(lock, condition));
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that if T1 is set off first, `flag = true` **always** happens before `f = flag` and if T2 is set off first the opposite is **always** true?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying that it's likely to happen first but it depends on the mood of the JVM - there are no guarantees. T1 might `yield` at some point. Or be suspended for the JIT compiler to do some work. I'll make it clearer.